# Target specific buttons - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to target specific buttons on a page

```
jQuery('button').on('click', function() {
  const num = this.dataset.xToggleable.match(/\d+$/);
  if (num) {
    jQuery('div[id^=privsec]').hide();
    jQuery(`div#privsec-${num}`).show();
  }
});
```

The buttons have the following markup:

```
<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-6" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-6" data-x-toggle-group="tab-group-e572-5"></button>
```

However I am getting this error when clicking on other buttons which do not have the aria properties set.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):1508)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle
```

How can I modify my code to avoid this?

The error appears when clicking this button in a popup on the page:

```
<button type="button" class="pum-close popmake-close" aria-label="Close">×</button>
```

Comment: Side note; you are intermixing jQuery accessor logic and native accessor logic.  That's a code smell.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/46q583sd/  I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: "However I am getting this error when clicking on other buttons which do not have the aria properties set." <= your logic has nothing to do with aria properties.  It has everything to do with the buttons having that data attribute on them.

Comment: I have listed the button code which errors out

Comment: ok this works thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic requires that the button has a `data-x-toggleable` attribute on them.  If there are buttons that do not have that attribute on them, there is no reason to add your event handler on them.  You can select just the elements that have that attribute using an attribute selector such as:

```
jQuery('button[data-x-toggleable]')
```